# Why doesn't pressing the spacebar whilst a `label` has focus check radio button in `[for=""]` attr?

Tags: html, label, accessibility

If I have the following html, when pressing the spacebar whilst the label has focus, why doesn't the radio it is associated with get checked?

```
<input type="radio" name="first-radio" id="first-radio-id">
<label for="first-radio-id" tabindex="1">The first radio</label>
```

This is making accessibility more difficult, is there a non-javascript workaround for this?

Here is a JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/atwright147/q0t53v78/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Label elements are not intended to receive the keyboard focus.

So simply remove the `tabindex` attribute and you will be able to check the radio control with the space bar when this control is focused.

If you want to control the visual aspect of a label associated to the input, you can change your CSS to:

```
input:focus + label {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I specifically need the label to trigger the checked state of it's associated radio. In my application the actual radio is hidden and a `<span>` is used to create a fake radio button. The radio never gets focus.

Comment: If the radio does not have focus, then you should rephrase your question to match your needs : *How do I simulate a radio button using ARIA?* See for instance: http://wiki.accede-web.com/en/notices/interfaces-riches-javascript/boutons-radio-simules

Comment: you are correct, it turned out that there was a flaw in the CSS which lead me down the wrong route. The solution was very similar to your code. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @jck nope, `tabindex` is already on the `input` element. Having a `tabindex` a non-interactive element makes it non accessible

Comment: @Adam do you mean that tabindex is by default on all `input` elements?

Comment: @jck yes all activable `input` elements (ie. not disabled or hidden)

Comment: @Adam so how does it that tab key doesn"t work if I remove tabindex? see here: https://jsfiddle.net/9a5u34c1/ and my version here: https://jsfiddle.net/uj7kgw65/

Comment: @jck you should open a new question for that. From what I see, your `input` elements have no name, so they belongs to the same group, only the first one is focused on tab press and you can select another element with arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the approach of having the user press the spacebar on the label, (apart from the fact that it doesn't work!) is that it's not natural behaviour to do that, so keyboard users just won't do it.

If you're replacing checkboxes with a JavaScript driven equivalent, what you should be doing is making your replacement element behave like a checkbox. In other words, allow it to receive tab focus and also have it toggle checked state when the spacebar is pressed on it. Leave the label to just being a label.

Comment: That's totally true, you can check my solution here that works while keeping accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround that keeps tabindex for accesibility and allows to check inputs buttons with spacebar

HTML

```
<form>
    <label id="radio1" tabindex="0">
        <input type="radio"><span class="label-text"></span></input>
    </label>
    <label id="radio2" tabindex="0">
        <input type="radio"><span class="label-text"></span></input>
    </label>
    <label id="radio3" tabindex="0">
        <input type="radio"><span class="label-text"></span></input>
    </label>
</form>
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    if(event.keyCode == '32'){
        if (document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() == "label"){
            document.activeElement.childNodes[1].checked = true;
        }
    }
});
```

The only downside is that the user needs to press two times tab key to go from an input to another.

BTW users with disability who have softwares like NV Access or Jaws use special keyboard shortcuts for web forms, because they know that using tab and space keys usually doesn't work.

Comment: While creative, and does answer the OP, I would **highly discourage** doing this.  Making the <label> a tabstop would reduce accessibility because the label does not have a `role`. Only interactive elements should be a tab stop. Just because there's a keyboard handler for the label does not make the label a "normal" interactive element.  It would be very confusing.  Some screen readers will say "clickable" when focus moves the label, giving the screen reader user a clue that you can select the element, but again, if the element doesn't have a role, it will be confusing.

Comment: @slugolicious I spent some hours with a disabled person who was using NV Access and this is the only solution we found for now. Can you fork my fiddle to show the good practice for doing this? https://jsfiddle.net/uj7kgw65/

Comment: as you can see here removing tabindex attribute makes the tab key not to work in the form: https://jsfiddle.net/9a5u34c1/

Comment: I ran the second fiddle example (9a5u34c1) with NVDA (from NV Access) on Firefox and was able to tab to each radio button and select it with the space bar.  Seems to work just fine.  The radio itself isn't coded properly (all the buttons should have the same `name` attribute), but it was fine for an initial test.  Radio buttons are pretty simple and if you stick with basic html, they work well.